# Setting up Model class using a LINQ call to db

Tags: c#, linq

I'm very new to MVC/LINQ so bear with me.  I'm wanting to check if that TransmissionStatus var is false and if so linq to db to pull the appropriate failed message.

```
class AuditLogManagement
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string MsgType { get; set; } //possibly enum?
    public AuditLogEventDetails EventDetails { get; set; }
    public string MsgContents { get; set; }
    public bool TransmissionStatus { get; set; }
    public string FailedTransmissionMsg
    {
        get
        {
            if (!TransmissionStatus)
            {
                //linq to db to return failed xmission message
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a model? Which bit are you stuck on? The database connection? The LINQ query? Also, every time you instantiate this class and `TransmissionStatus == false`, you'll make a database call - are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: @markpsmith the linq query.  I'm not sure thats what i want, what are the repercussions?

Comment: Is FailedTransmissionMsg housed in a separate table from the AuditLog? Also is the ID the FK to that table so you can reference the FailedTransmissionMsg?  Also keep in mind if you do this this way each time you loop you are making another call back to your entity.  Personally I would Simply do a join on your primary query and populate your FailedTransmissionMsg that way

Comment: The db tables haven't been created yet.  I was told to make the model first, then create the db tables w sample data @Bearcat9425

Comment: Well then really its up in the air, you can just store FailedTransmissionMsg within your AuditLogManagement table and you dont need to query another table, or you can create a related table and put it there. Then when you query AuditLogManagement I would join it to your FailedTransmissionMsg table on the matching ID's then you dont need to perform linq in your get.